# multiple Bool in one if-statement, or nested?

Tags: c#

OK, so I am learning c# and have the following code:

```
bool theTrue = true;
bool theFalse = false;

if ((theTrue = true) && (theFalse = false))
{
    Console.WriteLine(theTrue && theFalse); //False
}
```

I am a little bit curious about why the if-statement does not run through. I do understand that (true AND false) gives False.

As I understand it: (theFalse = false) is True...? (theFalse is false, so it must be true?)

But this code also does not run through, which makes it harder for me to do a nested if-statement:

```
if ((theFalse = false))
{ //something }
```

What is the proper way to accomplish running through the if-statement when (theTrue = true) and (theFalse = false)?

I am clearly missing something here...

Also, bonus question :-) when printing to Console, why does this

```
Console.WriteLine(theTrue && theFalse); //False
```

print "False" and not "false". In C# the value of the Bool is "false" without capital letter. Is it just a "feature", or is there something I need to be aware of?

Comment: You don't have to compare boolean values to get a true/false result. Use just `if (true && !theFalse)`. As for what gets printed, what you see is a *string* produced by calling `ToSting()` on the object. `Console.WriteLine` works with strings, so all arguments are formatted as strings by calling their `ToString()` method, unless you use a format string explicitly

Comment: BTW your code assigns new values to the variables, it doesn't compare them.

Comment: comparing is done via `==`, not `=`

Comment: You are assigning true and false values onto your boolean variables, '=' is assignment operator not comparison. if you want compare 2 things to each other if they are equal use '==' equality operator

Comment: Typographical error, question will not be helpful to future readers. Ironically, note that the compiler does warn about this general mistake, but only when there's just one assignment. _"warning CS0665: Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?"_. Your example has a more complex expression, so the warning is suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo

in c# `theTrue = true` is an assigment, not a bool check...

so you are assigning the variables, not comparing to a bool expression

```
if ((theTrue = true) && (theFalse = false))
```

do instead:

```
if ((theTrue == true) && (theFalse == false))
```

by the way and just a hint for you that are learning to code: bool checks can be simplified as

```
if (theTrue)
```

instead of

```
if (theTrue == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assigns new values to the variables, it doesn't compare them `theTrue = true` assigns the value `true` to `theTrue`. If you want to compare, use `==`.

Adding to that, assignments are expressions themselves, returning the assigned value. So :

```
if ((theTrue = true) && (theFalse = false))
```

is equivalent to :

```
if (true &&  false)
```

With booleans, though, you don't need to compare them at all. You could write

```
if (theTrue && !theFalse)
```

You only need an explicit comparison if you use nullable types (eg `bool?`) in which case the variable may be null. In that case, an explicit comparison is easier than checking the `.HasValue` property every time. You can write

```
if (theTrue == true && theFalse == false)
```

instead of

```
if (theTrue.HasValue && theTrue.Value && theFalse.HasValue && !theFalse.HasValue)
```

As for why printing a boolean value as a string to the console returns `False` or `True`, that's the string representation returned by [Boolean.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tostring?view=net-5.0).

[Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0) works with strings, so all arguments are formatted as strings by calling their `ToString()` method, unless you use a format string explicitly.

From the docs:

> Writes the text representation of the specified Boolean value, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.